# Autowiring SimpMessagingTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket

I've run into trouble trying to use SimpMessagingTemplate in a Service class. Here are the relevant Code Snippets:

**UserService.java** - Autowiring fails, template = null

```
@Service
public class UserService{
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    // Some Code

    public void tellUser(String username, String url) {
        // This is always true
        System.out.println("TEMPLATE NULL? " +(this.template == null));
        // Further code omitted
    }
}
```

**SocketController.java** - Autowiring works, Spring Websockets work as inteded.

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public void tellUser(String username, String url) {
        // False here, template is autowired correctly
        System.out.println("TEMPLATE NULL? " +(this.template == null));
        this.template.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/test/notify", new Greeting("USER SPECIFIC MESSAGE: " + url));
    }
}
```

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/user", "/test");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/test").withSockJS();

    }
}
```

So basically the autowiring works in my Controller class, but not in my Service. I do need to invoke a convertAndSendToUser manually in a Service. What's the difference for Autowiring SimpMessagingTemplate between a Controller and a Service? Any input on why this might happen is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your Spring Annotation-based Configs?

Comment: Did u ever find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Initially there are not any differences between controller autowired and service autowired (and if the SimpMessagingTemplate is available in controller, it have to be available in service class too), unless spring is not loading the service class.

How you load your beans? Maybe the package of service class is not covered by auto-scan? are you defining you beans in a context XML?

Comment: There is no specific config for it because Spring takes care of the autowiring itself without requiring a specific configuration in this case. As I said, it works just fine in the Controller, but doesn't in my service. @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xy.*") is set to scan the whole project